# About the definition of the dualizing module for a Noetherian local ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra

The page 329 of the book "Modular Forms and Fermat Last Theorem" says that:

[image]

I have two questions about this equivalence.

1. In the cited [reference](http://matematicas.unex.es/%7Enavarro/res/localcohomology.pdf), the definition further requests that the set of associated prime idals of $I$ is $\{\mathfrak{M}\}$ (if I understand correctly), but I don't think this can be concluded from (ii).
2. Also in the cited reference, it says that the functor ${\rm Hom}_R(-,I)$ actually gives an anti-isomorphism between the category of finitely generated $\hat{R}$-modules and the category of Artinian $R$-modules, but in (i) $\hat{R}$ is replaced by $R$. Since $I$ is Artinian as $R$-module and ${\rm Hom}_R(I,I)=\hat{R}$, this replacement holds true only when $\hat{R}$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. This seems to be true only in rare cases.

Comment: Is $R$ Artinian here? This definition of the dualizing module does not behave well if $\dim R>0$, as far as I know.